# How can I activate node version on mac

Tags: node.js

I try to change the node version on mac m1 pro macOs 13,
I do the following commands:

1. sudo npm cache clean -f
2. sudo npm install -g n
3. sudo n stable

but it is not change, the result is:

```
copying : node/18.12.0
installed : v18.12.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v17.8.0 at /opt/homebrew/bin/node
```

How can I activate the installed version?

Comment: Seems the homebrew node version has priority, so uninstall the homebrew node version and then run `hash -r` or open a new shell. Or create a symlink to `/usr/local/bin/node` in a directory that has a higher priority in your `PATH`.

Comment: I'll say go with `nvm` it lets you install multiple node versions and use them according to your project requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar case and I was able to resolve it like below

```
   installed : v20.8.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v16.15.0 at /Users/me/.config/nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node
```

Command> node -v
v16.15.0

```
nvm deactivate 16.15.0
nvm uninstall 16.15.0
Uninstalled node v16.15.0
```

```
Command> node -v
v20.8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The active node is installed using homebrew. Therefore, you could remove the node installed using the homebrew and install it from the Mac Installer from https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

In addition to that, you might need to add the path variable to .zshrc. For that, In your terminal nano ~/.zshrc then add the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/[your username]/.npm-packages/bin
```

Also, if you need to use multiple node versions in a single machine you can use a node version manager[1].

[1] https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 and 3 are the same so maybe you did it but… you can try to
`n uninstall 17.8.0` followed by `sudo n` to select the desired version.